# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration - Linux Maven

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to run a maven project on Linux Mint using Eclipse DSL and Java developer version. I have imported the project and fixed most of the errors (there was a lot) and now I'm down to 12 which are all in my pom.xml files the errors say: "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com .coveo:fmt-maven-plugin:2.8format (execution: code-formatter, phase: compile) if I open the pom file the line that causes the error is the parent tag

[image]

Comment: Eclipse or intellij or vscode  may complain about anything, it is more wise to just run mvn from command line and see if it works, package is built. and without seeing your pom.xml it is really hard to find the problem :) you know we are not telepaths who can read your mind from internet :)